# Match Type directly in F# (not the object, the actual System.Type)

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

I know how match on the Type of a object, but how directly on the Type object?

This not work:

```
    let toType = p.PropertyType 

    match toType with
    | System.Enum -> 
    | System.Int32 ->
```

PD: Yes, I need to match the type. I don't have the object because I'm reflecting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't match on `System.Type` itself, because it's not an F# destructurable type. Same way you can't match, for example, on `StreamReader` or on `StringBuilder`, etc.

But you can perfectly well *compare* types, e.g.:

```
if t = typeof<Enum> then ...
elif t = typeof<Int32> then ...
else ...
```

However, keep in mind that this will only give you strict equality. It will not give you subtypes. For example, `typeof<DayOfWeek> <> typeof<Enum>`.
In order to check for subtypes as well, use the [`Type.IsAssignableFrom` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if typeof<Enum>.IsAssignableFrom t then ...
elif typeof<Int32>.IsAssignableFrom t then ...
else ...
```

(note that for `Int32` simple comparison would have been enough, because `Int32` is a sealed type, so it cannot have subtypes; but I still kept `IsAssignableFrom` there for consistency)

---

And if you really want to use the `match` syntax, you can always make yourself an [active pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns).

Unfortunately, you can't use angle brackets in patterns (for whatever reason), so `match x with IsType typeof<Enum>` would be impossible. But you *can* use quotations in patterns, and quotations *can* contain angle brackets within them, so you *can* do `match x with IsType <@ typeof<Enum> @>`. Unfortunately, this means that the active pattern would be rather complex and not so performant:

```
let (|IsType|_|) (a: FSharp.Quotations.Expr<System.Type>) (t: System.Type) : unit option = 
    match a with
    | FSharp.Quotations.Patterns.Call (None, m, []) when m.Name = "TypeOf" -> 
        let testAgainst = m.GetGenericArguments().[0]
        if testAgainst.IsAssignableFrom t
            then Some()
            else None
    | _ -> 
        None

match t with
| IsType <@ typeof<Enum> @> -> "enum"
| IsType <@ typeof<Int32> @> -> "int"
| _ -> "don't know"
```

This is rather non-trivial, so I wouldn't recommend it. Just as a mental exercise :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `when` clause and use the `typeof` operator:

```
let toType = p.PropertyType 

match toType with
| t when t = typeof<System.Enum> -> 
| t when t = typeof<System.Int32> ->
```

Comment: A `match` expression consisting of nothing but `when` clauses is no better (and I would argue even worse) than a series of `if`/`elif`/`else`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Is that a matter of fact or a matter of opinion?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in pattern matching for this. Enum is not even a type. It's a type of type. I think you'll just need to do the work manually:

```
open System
let whichType (t:Type) =
    if t.IsEnum then "enum"
    elif t = typeof<int> then "int"
    else "other"

whichType (DayOfWeek.Monday.GetType()) // "enum"
whichType ((1).GetType()) // "int"
whichType ("".GetType()) // "other"
```